# Why can a positive integer be written "in base p"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I've come across a statement in Gouvea's "p-adic Numbers" that I'm confused about. Suppose $m$ is a positive integer and $p$ is prime. Why is it true that we can write $m=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots + a_np^n$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}, 0\leq a_i\leq p-1$?

Comment: I think you meant $a_1p$ instead of $a_p$.  This has nothing to do with primes...you can write any natural number in any integral base.  The argument is the same for base $n$ as it is for base $10$.

Comment: You prove it by strong induction on $m$ and the division algorithm. And yes, as lulu says, it should be $a_1p,$ not $a_p.$ Given any positive integer $b>1$ you can write any positive integer $m$ in base $b.$

Comment: Because the question specifies positive integers, I think it's worth pointing out that the p-adics also give you the ability to write all negative integers in base p as well - without the need of a negative sign!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with $p$ but any integer greater than $1$ (such as $10$) can do that.  That is simply digital notation.

All numbers can be written as $m=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots + a_np^n$ for the *EXACTLY* same reason all numbers can be written as $m = m=a_0+a_1*10+a_2*100+\cdots + a_n10^n$ where $a_i = 0......9$, which is how we have been counting numbers all our lives.

$1456 = 6 + 5*10 + 4*10^2 + 1*10^3$ for example.

We've been doing this all our lives!

...

Okay, why *can* we write all numbers in decimal notation?  (Just because we've done it since we learned to count and never questioned it doesn't answer *why* we can do it.)

---

To begin with $a_0$ is found by taking the remainder of $m$ when divided by $10$... or $p$.  All numbers will have a remainder when divided by $p$.  That is the division theorem[1].  For all integers $m$ and all positive integer $p$ there is a unique $b$ and $r$ so that $m = r + bp; 0\le r < p$.

So let $a_0 = r$.  And $m = a_0 + bp$.

Now take the $b$ and do the same thing.  There are unique $c$ and $s$ so that $b = s + cp; 0\le s < p-1$.  Let $a_1 = s$ and we have

$m = a_0 + bp = a_0 + (a_1 + cp)p = a_0 + a_1*p + cp^2$.

Now just repeat for $c$.  $c = t + dp; 0\le t < p-1$ so $a_2 = t$ and

$m = a_0 + bp = a_0 + (a_1 + cp)p = a_0 + a_1*p + cp^2$

$= a_0 + a_1*p + (t+ dp)p^2 = a_0 + a_1*p + a_2p^2 + dp^3$

.... and keep going.

As $m$ is finite and the sum we are creating involves higher and higher powers of $p$ we'll have to eventually reach a highest power of $p$.  So this must end sometime.

There's nothing magical about the number $10$ and we could use any number.  So we could use a prime $p$.

This is called putting numbers in base $p$ and it is often basic education in grade school.

For example to convert $1235$ into base $7$ we find the remainder of $1235$ when divided by $7$.

$1235 = 3 + 7*176$.  So $a_0 = 3$

Then we find the remainder of $176$.  $176 = 1 + 25*7$ so $a_1 = 1$

Then we find the remainder of $25$.  $25 = 4 + 3*7$ so $a_2 = 4$

Then we find the remainder of $3$.  $3 = 3$ so $a_3 = 3$ and we are done.

So $1235 = 3413_7$ in base seven where

$3413_ 7 = 3 + 1*7 + 4*7^2 + 3*7^3$

$= 3 + 7(1 + 7(4 + 7(3))$

$= 3 + 7(1 + 7(25))$

$=3 + 7(176)$

$1235$

====

[1] Actually proving the division theorem--- that for all integers $m$ and positive integer $p$ there is are unique integers $b, r; 0 \le r < p-1$ so that $m = bp + r$--- is not trivial.

But I assume that is not the level of depth that was intended by the question.

Comment: Technically, the "dec" in "decimal" is for "10," so "decimal" really means base $10.$

Comment: True... And I worried about that when I typed it.  What is the technical term for base x notation when the base is unspecified?  Is it a common term that everyone would recognize if I said "That's just *blank* notation".

Comment: Oh, .... I guess "That's just digital representation" might be what I have in mind.

Comment: Yeah, digital I'd guess is best. Although even digit means "finger," again implying base $10.$ :)

Comment: That's etymology.  Not usage.  Digital derived from 10 fingers but it doesn't mean 10 fingers.  Decimal derived from 10 and ... does it mean base 10? Well, it does when we say binary vs. octal vs. decimal. so ... yes.  My worry about using "digital" is that in refers to using digits but *not* in that they represent a power of a persistent base.  Which decimal and binary specifically do.

Comment: Yeah, I was kidding. Hence the :) smiley.

Comment: Yeah, I got that.  But I am wondering what is the proper term.  Digit reprentation doesn't nesc. mean specific base.  And decimal means specifically base ten.  And if I said "That's just Base p representation!" it defeats my purpose of pointing out that we've been doing this all our lives.

Answer (score 0):

In doubt, try induction.

For $m=1$, we can take $n=0$, $a_0=0$.

Assume $m=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\ldots +a_np^n$. Wlog $a_n<p-1$ (or else append a summand $0\cdot p^{n+1}$ and increase $n$).
Let $k=\min\{\,j\ge 0\mid a_j<p-1\,\}$ and then $$b_j=\begin{cases}0,&j<k\\
a_j+1,&j=k\\a_j,&j>k\end{cases} $$
Then the $0\le b_j\le p-1$ for all $j$ and one checks that $b_0+b_1p+\ldots +b_np^n=m+1$.
Indeed,
$$(b_0+b_0p+\ldots+b_np^n)-(a_0+a_0p+\ldots+a_np^n)\\=-(p-1)(1+p+\ldots+p^{k-1})+p^k=-(p^k-1)-p^k=1$$

*Remark:* nowhere did we use that $p$ is prime. Any integer $p\ge 2$ would do.